# Why is Pin::map_unchecked unsafe？

Tags: rust, unsafe, rust-pin

```
pub unsafe fn map_unchecked<U, F>(self, func: F) -> Pin<&'a U>
where
    F: FnOnce(&T) -> &U,
    U: ?Sized,
```

`FnOnce(&T) -> &U` params is a reference so it can't move `T` anyway. Why is this function `unsafe`?

There is a same question [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55766), but can't understand this example:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

Almost all `unsafe` functions in the Rust standard library have documentation explaining why. From the documentation for [`Pin::map_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.map_unchecked):

> Constructs a new pin by mapping the interior value.
>
> For example, if you wanted to get a `Pin` of a field of something, you could use this to get access to that field in one line of code. However, there are several gotchas with these “pinning projections”; see the [`pin` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning) documentation for further details on that topic.
>
> #### Safety
>
> This function is unsafe. You must guarantee that the data you return will not move so long as the argument value does not move (for example, because it is one of the fields of that value), and also that you do not move out of the argument you receive to the interior function.

This is essentially the same reason why `Pin::new_unchecked` is unsafe. Pinning a value means that it must *never move again* not just while protected by the `Pin`. However, this function alone cannot ensure that guarantee and must be provided by the developer using it.

The `pin` module that is linked includes many requirements that must be followed for *structural pinning* i.e. if getting a field from `Pin<&Self>` requires the field to also be pinned which is a primary reason to use `map_unchecked`. Requirements include: you cannot give `&mut` access to it elsewhere, it cannot be moved from even in the `Drop` implementation, it cannot be deallocated unless it is dropped, etc.

Comment: thx, but my question is, it seems that there is no chance to move &T and &U. the param is &, not &mut.

Comment: @bilosikia Its not really about moving `&T` or `&T` inside the function, but rather not moving them *outside* the function. Consider [this example on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60bb63fc1337687f990a8f24da2f488e) where the pinned result of `map_unchecked` is later moved-out-of, which violates the safety requirements of `Pin`.

Comment: The unsafe block ends before the s.name is taken, so there is no pined object, so no requirements are violated

Comment: @bilosikia You have misunderstood Pin's safety requirements. I mentioned it in my answer: "*Pinning a value means that it must *never move again* [never ever ever] not just while protected by the `Pin`."* Take a look at the examples in the documentation for [`Pin::new_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new_unchecked) if you are not convinced.

Comment: you are right,  you have solved my doubts, thank you very much,